# How to exclude test dependencies from a shaded maven jar?

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-3, maven-shade-plugin

I'm using the maven-shade-plugin and I'd like to exclude not only my test code, but my test dependencies in the shaded jar. I realize I can specifically exclude certain artifacts (like junit), but that's a good bit of work and prone to some error most likely.

I'm setting `minimizeJar` to true, but I still see my Junit and Mockito dependencies showing up. Is there just no way to exclude all test scoped dependencies via configuration?

Comment: Which version of shade plugin are you using? And how does your pom look like? I created a test project with Junit as test scope and the shade plugin did not package it. it is possible that one other lib not in test scope has Junit as dependency?

Comment: @mszalbach It was a combination of two things: One, there was a test dependency that was mistakenly declared as compile. Two, there was a test dependency that include the .java files in its jar, and I didn't notice the extension when I was looking at the shaded jar. So, you're right, the test dependency .class files do not get packaged.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure your test dependencies in the `test` scope:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
...
```

To check if your dependency setup use

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

Comment: @ryzmek It was a combination of two things: One, there was a test dependency that was mistakenly declared as compile. Two, there was a test dependency that included the .java files in its jar, and I didn't notice the extension when I was looking at the shaded jar.

Comment: I thought it might be the case. That's why I suggested `dependency:tree`. It's a really useful tool