# Remove test dependencies from deployed POM

Tags: maven

I have a fairly typical `pom.xml` which builds a jar:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-lib</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>...</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I thought it'd be nice to remove the test dependencies (junit-jupiter and its dependencies) from the copy of the POM which is deployed with the jar, just to avoid imposing them on users of the jar. After all, test code isn't included in the deployed jar, so it shouldn't matter to users of the jar how the tests are written.

I figured this would be a common use case for `maven-shade-plugin`. But this use case doesn't seem to be mentioned in its documentation. And I wasn't able to make the shade plugin remove the `junit-jupiter` dependency from the reduced POM.

Is there a straightforward way to remove dependencies from the deployed POM? Am I worrying about nothing?

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16466490/13317), but it seems to be about removing test dependency contents from the uber jar. In my case, I'm not actually creating an uber jar. I'm just trying to use the shade plugin for its ability to rewrite the POM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove unnecessary parts from the deployed POM, you can use the flatten maven plugin:

https://www.mojohaus.org/flatten-maven-plugin/flatten-mojo.html

One of the features is to remove the test dependencies.